# How to Find Encryption Type by Seeing Encrypted Text?

Tags: encryption, brute-force, decryption, encoding

When I submit an Customer Reference ID in an Android Application it POSTs an Encrypted String to an API Endpoint.

For example, if I enter the following CR ID :

"CR-13261150"

it POSTs the following Encrypted Data:

```
splainText : "vpEz/Vm8Yi9v5/fzNE+MDoMIQGZ0vNvjPuX8UNAi26c="

     Count : 31
```

i can say count is based on Length of Customer ID,if the lenght is 11 then count is 31. (But All Valid Customer ID will have Length 11 for Sure)

Now let's assume if I submit the same CR ID in the following minute the Encrypted String Changes. But if I submit the same CR ID in the very same minute then for some reason I get the very same Encrypted String.

Please tell Me Which Encyption Method was Used and How to Decrypt it to Orginal Text.

Comment: Your second text looks like based encoded but that is not an encryption. If the actual data is encrypted then this is the end. A good encryption outputs data the is not distinguishable from random data. The only property you may be able to identify from the encrypted text if the algorithm is a block cipher or a stream cipher (based on it's length).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Good encryption is indistinguishable from random data.

Comment: The problem isn't that the question was misunderstood, but rather that the question is off-topic here. We aren't the reverse engineering stack.

Answer (score 3):

This is XOR encryption, with the key `d684babf42876f1a2246973928c118f642398921e150882c4f912b`

The following python script will decrypt the cyphertext:

```
import base64

cyphertextb64='k9Ca7yroAX8CDvhUTeA512MYqADAcakNbrAK'
keyb16='d684babf42876f1a2246973928c118f642398921e150882c4f912b'

cyphertextb16=base64.b64decode(cyphertextb64).hex()

#XOR Decryption:
plaintexthex=hex(int(cyphertextb16, 16) ^ int(keyb16, 16))  

plaintextbytes=bytes.fromhex(plaintexthex[2:])
plaintext=plaintextbytes.decode("utf-8")
print(plaintext)
```

This produces the decrypted plaintext, which is:

```
ET Phone Home!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

---

Edit:

In response to the question in the comment below about how I went about reverse-engineering this:

First, I did this to show that questions like this are pointless, because you can use a cipher like XOR to make any ciphertext decrypt to any plaintext you want, using a carefully chosen key.

As to how I chose the key:  If you have A xor B = C then, the following is also true:

```
A xor C = B
C xor B = A
```

So, I made the given ciphertext A, and I made my wanted plaintext ('ET Phone Home!!!!!!!!!!!!!!') B, and used the first equation above to find the key, C.

This can be done using the following python script:

```
import base64

cyphertextb64='k9Ca7yroAX8CDvhUTeA512MYqADAcakNbrAK'
plaintext='ET Phone Home!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
 
cyphertextb16=base64.b64decode(cyphertextb64).hex()
plaintextbytes=plaintext.encode("utf-8")
plaintextb16=plaintextbytes.hex()

#XOR:
key=hex( int(plaintextb16, 16) ^ int(cyphertextb16, 16) )

print('key:', key[2:])
```

Which produces:

```
key: d684babf42876f1a2246973928c118f642398921e150882c4f912b
```

Sure enough, 'decrypting' the given cyphertext by XORing it with the key above produces the wanted plaintext, as shown in the first script above.

Comment: How do you go about reverse engineering that please?

Comment: @RodrigoMurillo  See edit that I made above in my answer.

Comment: Ah... chosen plain text!  Got it well done thanks

Comment: @RodrigoMurillo I'd argue it's the infamous chosen key-attack ;)

Comment: @mti2935 Totally disagree, as explained in great detail in my completely different answer. ;)

Comment: Very clever, @hft!

Comment: Agreed @vidarlo clever.  Never learned so much from a "bad" question. Thanks

Comment: @RodrigoMurillo see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/217862/what-if-the-attacker-tamper-the-iv-used-in-the-block-cipher-cbc-mode/ for how a similar type of attack can be used with AES-CBC decryption, when the integrity of the IV is not verified.

Answer (score 1):

This is XOR encryption with the key `c1bff2865e80211e71659d306d8119b5027c8871b514da7907df64`

The following python script will decrypt the cyphertext:

```
import base64

cyphertextb64='k9Ca7yroAX8CDvhUTeA512MYqADAcakNbrAK'
keyb16='c1bff2865e80211e71659d306d8119b5027c8871b514da7907df64'

cyphertextb16=base64.b64decode(cyphertextb64).hex()

#XOR Decryption:
plaintexthex=hex(int(cyphertextb16, 16) ^ int(keyb16, 16))  

plaintextbytes=bytes.fromhex(plaintexthex[2:])
plaintext=plaintextbytes.decode("utf-8")
print(plaintext)
```

This produces the decrypted plaintext, which is:

```
`Rohith asked a bad question`
```